# PHP/HTML,how can I hide the current article from sidebar if already open?

Tags: php

I would like to hide the article from the sidebar if it is already open, but I don't know how it can be done. I'm a newbie, sorry about that.

I am using MySqli **select random** to show 8 articles in a sidebar.
The articles are saved in a variable and then I echo them on a different page.

Can anyone help me out or tell me how should I do this. What kind of code to use. Thank You.

Here is the article code.

```
case'article':
    $get_article = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT title,link,excerpt,description_1,description_2,description_3,description_4,description_5,description_6,description_7,description_8,description_9,description_10,description_11,description_12 from `articles_".LANG."` where link = '".$_GET['article']."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_article) != 1){
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        $page = '404';
    }
    else{
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_article);
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['excerpt'];
        $content_url= 'http://www.example.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/';
        $meta_img = 'http://www.sub.example.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'] .'/1.jpg';
        $files = glob('/home/site/sub.example.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

        $total = count($files);

        for($i = 1;$i <= $total; $i++){
            if(is_file('/home/site/sub.example.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$i.'.jpg')){
                $picture = $i.'.jpg';
            }
            elseif(is_file('/home/site/sub.site.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$i.'.jpeg')){
                $picture = $i.'.jpeg';
            }
            $pictures .= '<div class="article_box"><h3 class="top_img_description">'.$row['description_'.$i]. '</h3>'.'<div class="single_img_container"><img src="http://sub.example.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$picture.'"/></div></div>';
        }
```

Here is the sidebar code.

```
$article_sidebar = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT title,link from `articles_".LANG."`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($article_sidebar)){

if(is_file('/home/site/sub.example.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row2['link'].'/1.jpg')) {
    $file='http://sub.example.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row2['link'].'/1.jpg';
}

$sidebar_articles .= '<div class="article">
        <div class="article_thumb">'.'<a href="/'.LANG.'/'.$row2['link'].'/"><img src="'.$file.'"/></a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="feed_title">
            <a href="/'.LANG.'/'.$row2['link'].'/">'.$row2['title'].'</a>
        </h3>
    </div>';    
}
```

And here is the a screenshot of what I want.

[image]

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I added it , ty

Comment: Stick to the answer from @Bernhard. `$currentid` is `$_GET['article']` in your case. But please read into SQL injection and prepared statements, because your code is vulnerable for attacks.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I tried but I get syntax error.Thank you tho.I will see what I can do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT title,link from `articles_".LANG."`WHERE id <> ".$currentid." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8"
```

Exclude the id of the current displayed element in your query. This is done for example by using <>. And don't forget to check the values before you put them in a mysql-query!

Comment: And how will it know the id of the current article ? will it work if i do this only in the sidebar Selection ?thank you.

Comment: I guess you have the ID in the link of your article-page, don't you?

Comment: Its `... WHERE link <> '" . $_GET['article'] . "' ...`, which is very vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Bernhard ,I dont think it has an ID , I am using a switch case statment to switch between pages . Default/Article , when I click on an article it opens the article page and shows  the content of variables.

Comment: Well it seams this fixed it WHERE link <> '" . $_GET['article'] . "' , its working ,thank you, @PhilippMaurer I will see how I can make it more secure.THank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript if want to be able to switch through articles at some point without the page reloading. Add a unique class to all articles on the right and the main article on the page (a unique ID perhaps) and compare this to the main section. If the two match then apply apply a hidden class or change it's **display** property to **none**.

If you want to do this server side and switching between articles causes the page to refresh, you should apply a similar approach to the above. Store some reference to the current 'main' article and wrap the sidebar articles in a foreach.

In this foreach, wrap each addition to the sidebar html in an if statement which compares the the current value with that of the main article.

eg.

```
if ( $currentArticleId !== $mainArticleId )
{

$sidebar_articles .= '<div class="article">
        <div class="article_thumb">'.'<a href="/'.LANG.'/'.$row2['link'].'/"><img src="'.$file.'"/></a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="feed_title">
            <a href="/'.LANG.'/'.$row2['link'].'/">'.$row2['title'].'</a>
        </h3>
    </div>';  

...
```